# Зачем сравнивать индекс массива со значением?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть метод добавки в массив элемента.
Код рабочий, из примера, но не могу понять его суть.
Помогите понять, как он работает?

Затрудняет вот эта часть: `if(a[j] > value)` - зачем сравнивать индекс массива со значением? что это дает?

```
public void insert(long value) // Вставка элемента в массив
{
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<nElems; j++) // Определение позиции вставки
    if(a[j] > value) // (линейный поиск)
    break;
    for(int k=nElems; k>j; k--) // Перемещение последующих элементов
    a[k] = a[k-1];
    a[j] = value; // Вставка
    nElems++;
```

Comment: Так сравнивается не индекс массива а значение по этому индексу

Comment: понел это сортировка по значению ... Блин долгож доходило )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void insert(long value) // Вставка элемента в массив
{
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<nElems; j++) // Идем по всем элементам
        if(a[j] > value)    // Если элемент больше искомого значения
            break;          // то прекращаем цикл

    for(int k=nElems; k>j; k--) // Для всех последующих элементов
        a[k] = a[k-1];          // перемещаем их на 1 к концу
```

Так понятнее?

Comment: блин ))))))Я думл 1 цикл внутри другого ...

Comment: А вы всегда форматируйте код. Это **ОЧЕНЬ** важно для понимания кода, поверьте.